# Magento: Generating Thousands of Products and Configurable Attributes

Tags: php, excel, magento, magento-1.5

I've looked all over Google and here at SO and I just can't find a solution.

I have a store that sells custom computers. Customers are able to select a model and then configure all aspects of the computer.

I was directed to the [SCP Extension](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/) for managing my Configurable Products: "With SCP you can set a price for each combination of attribute values, e.g. Standard, Intel, 4GB RAM = $500." And that works marvelously.

However, as I've started creating my products, I didn't anticipate having to create literally thousands and thousands of Simple Products for every single, minute customization... AND THEN creating the Configurable Product. Seriously... THOUSANDS! It would probably take me 2 solid weeks of full-time simple product creation.

Having said that, is there a way to create am Excel or Numbers document and then simulate all possible variations? I believe it's called a Matrix.

I mean, how else does anyone put together a shop that sells more than 20 T-Shirts with two configurable attributes (Size, Color)?

Comment: Did you see this extension http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html ?

Comment: Oh wow... Zyava... no I haven't. You should put this as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added my comment as answer.

> Did you see this extension [mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html](http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong! :-)

Whereas the components themselves are the inventory items, and you have a large and arbitrarily-variable combination of those inventory items to create a purchasable product, you will benefit from using the *Bundle* product type. It allows you to present groups of products together and to set required and optional components.

For frontend example, see: http://demo.magentocommerce.com/my-computer.html

For backend, see: http://demo-admin.magentocommerce.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/165/

Comment: Ben, thanks for the reply. I've seen so many people complaining about this all over the web. Bundles products still requires a ton of attribute creation, no?

Comment: At some point, you have to configure all of your products, but this wou be true in any system. Good luck!

Comment: "Bundle with dynamic pricing cannot include custom defined options. Options will not be saved." - Looks like a deal breaker for me. At times I need to be able to allow a customer to upload a file with their order. Any way around this?